# Making group constraints in Regex in android

Tags: java, android, regex

So I have this String:

```
         String articleContent  = "dfgh{jdf%g{%qf234ad%22!#$56a%}vzsams{%3%45%}678456{78";
```

I want to remove everything between {%  %}

So result would be something like :

```
        dfgh{jdf%gvzsams678456{78
```

I tried this:

```
         String regex = "[{%][^[%}]&&\\p{Graph}]*[%}]";
         String abc = articleContent.replaceAll(regex, "");
```

But what I get is:

```
         dfghfgqf234ad}vzsams3}678456{78
```

What I suppose I'm doing wrong is not able to make a group of "{%" instead of [{%] which is like an or condition { or % .

Any suggestions?

**EDIT 1:**
The string that I have taken is just for an example. It can have any special characters in between {% and %} not only ! and %

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with this pattern:

```
String regex = "\\{%(?>[^%]++|%(?!}))*%}";
```

explanations:

The goal of this pattern is to reduce at the minimum the number of backtracks:

```
\\{%         # { need to be escaped
(?>          # open an atomic group *
   [^%]++    # all characters but %, one or more times (possessive *)
  |          # OR
   %(?!})    # % not followed by } (<-no need to escape)
)*           # close the atomic group, repeat zero or more times
%}
```

*(* more informations about [possessive quantifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html) and [atomic groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html))*

Comment: If input can contain something like `{%abc%%}` it will fail for it since `%++(?!})` will fail for `%%}` so regexs cursor will be before it and `%}` wont be able to match it. In this case unfortunately `%+(?!})` would be better. But if such input is impossible it is correct so I guess you deserve +1 :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and it works on this string but I will have a generic string with unknown special characters. Sorry I did not mention it before.

Comment: @user2156936: this pattern allows all characters special or not.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
String abc = articleContent.replaceAll("\\{%.*?%}", "")
```

Since `{` is special characters you need to escape it. You can do this with  `\\{` or `[{]`.

Now to match all characters between `{%` and `%}` you can use `{%.*%}`, but `*` quantifier is greedy so it will match maximal possible substring between first `{%` and last `%}`. To make it match minimal substring we need to add `?` after `*` making it reluctant.

You can find more info about quantifiers [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html).